# Does the update_all method in ActiveRecord return the number of rows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to set the 'lock' column on a row only if it is not already set.  Race conditions are likely and performance is important so this must be done in a single query.  I think the solution should look like this:

```
class MyModel
  def lock(worker)
    cnt = MyModel.where(id: self.id, lock: nil).update_all(:lock=>worker.name)
    cnt == 1
  end
end
```

Does the `update_all` method actually return the number of rows effected like it does in DataMapper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does in ActiveRecord as in DataMapper